# When are the cotangent and tangent sheaves isomorphic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, derham-cohomology

Let $X$ be an $S$-scheme. Under what conditions, if any, is the cotangent sheaf $\Omega_{X/S}$ isomorphic to the tangent sheaf $\Theta_{X/S}$ as $\mathcal{O}_X$- modules? For example, given a nonsingular variety $V$ over a field $k$, what conditions could $V$ satisfy to ensure that such an isomorphism would exist?

@PraphullaKoushik Here are my thoughts: If $X$ is a smooth variety of dimension $n$ over a field $k$, then we know that the $\Omega_{X/k}$ is locally free of rank $n$, and so is $\Theta_{X/k}$. At each point, we could find various isomorphisms between the stalks of $\Omega_{X/k}$ and $\Theta_{X/k}$ (this just follows because they are free modules over the respective local rings). However, this does not admit globally, i.e. there does not neccesarily exist a global section admitting the desired isomorphism. If we were to remove a particular subset of points from the variety, then we might be able to find such an isomorphism. However, I was curious if there were particular characterizations of the variety for which this is known!

Comment: Do you want to share your thoughts on this?

Comment: This'd be a nondegenerate bilinear form on the (co)tangent bundle, so a section of T*(X/S) ⊗ T*(X/S). Not sure if there's more you can say at this level of generality.

Comment: @skd There is another idea, take a global section $g$ of $T^* (X/S) \otimes T^* (X/S)$ (as you write) and remove the points from $X$ for which the restriction of $g$ at any point $p\in X$ is non-degenerate. This would determine a subset of $X$ for which $g$ becomes is a non-degenerate bilinear form. But this is itself very general, and we don't know whether or not this subset could be consider an open/closed subscheme.

Comment: Have you thought about it when V is a curve, or a surface?

Comment: If you take arbitrary smooth varieties (over a field, say complex numbers), as you said, any point has a neighborhood where what you say is true, since $\Omega$ and $T$ both will be free, not just locally free. So, it is difficult to answer such a question. So, let us further assume that $X$ is projective. Then, the only varieties satisfying your hypothesis that comes to mind are abelian varieties.

Comment: If $X$ is a smooth surface, then we always have an isomorphism $T_X \cong \Omega_X \otimes \omega_X$, coming from the perfect pairing $\Omega_X\times \Omega_X\to k$. So, $T_X\cong \Omega_X$ if and only if $\omega_X$ is trivial, i.e., for abelian and K3 surfaces.

Comment: On the other hand, for Calabi-Yau threefolds $T_X=\Omega^2_X$, and so a necessary condition for this type of variety is $h^{11}=h^{21}$, ie the Hodge diamond is symmetric. This is quite rare.

Comment: Two remarks: firstly (this hasn't been said yet), it's always true on an abelian variety (more generally, group scheme over $k$), because both are trivial. Secondly, if $T_X \cong \Omega_X$ for $X$ smooth, then taking determinants we conclude that $\omega_X$ is $2$-torsion. In even dimension an argument like @DevlinMallory's (but on $\Omega^{n/2}_X$) shows that $\omega_X$ is in fact trivial.